# Polymer does not support Edge browser?

Tags: polymer, paper-elements, microsoft-edge

I just tried my Polymer Paper Elements 1.0 based web app on the Windows 10 Edge browser and the UI elements do not render. The UI looks fine in other browsers. I navigated the Edge browser to the official Paper Elements 1.0 catalog and much of the UI does not render there either. Before I flush my Paper Elements work down the toilet I just want to be sure... Does anyone know of a tweak that will allow Paper Elements to work in the Edge browser?

Comment: Update: I have found that although the component lists in the Polymer catalog do not render correctly in the Edge browser, the Paper Elements demo pages do appear to render correctly if you manually enter their URLs. Still investigating...

Comment: Polymer Elements (Core elements and Paper elements, v. 0.5) seem to work so far for my app in Windows 10 Edge. Hence, seems to be an issue related to v.1.0 (that's why I rolled back from v 1.0 back to v. 0.5 meanwhile).

Answer (score 2):

The problem the Edge browser currently has with the Polymer catalog pages was a red herring. There were two pieces of code in my JavaScript that were causing problems for Paper Elements when running on Edge (or IE):

1) A `var console;` declaration at the top of a file. The line was present to keep JSHint happy.

2) Line `document.domain = 'mydomain.com';` which was being used to relax CORS security enough to allow accessing resources from subdomains of mydomain.com.

Otherwise, Paper Elements seem to work fine with the Edge browser.